# Cordova app for Android (builded in XDK) blocks Ajax-requests over HTTPS

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, https

First of all, regular Ajax-requests over http works fine. Problem begins when I'm trying to perform completely the same Ajax-request (GET) over https.

While debugging using WEINRE, I can see in network tab that requests are staying in pending state, but I get the fake empty response, that contains status=0 and other properties empty. More than it, server's side never get these requests. Looks like Android just doesn't let them go.

Before building app, I set wildcards `*` in build settings in XDK everywhere: `<access>`, `<allow-intent>`, `<allow-navigation>`. I also added the following CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

**Additional facts:**

1) If I build the same app for iOS, it works without any problems. So this is Android trouble only.

2) Ajax-requests over https works in Android sometimes, but rarely. So I can't say that they are blocked everytime, but I also can't find out conditions when it works and when it doesn't. But most of the times it doesn't work.

3) It worked fine some time ago. The behavior that I'm talking about appeared not long ago. I thought that this problem might be connected with SSL certificate on server side (for example, it was expired ), but desktop browsers don't report about any problems. The URL string still is green.

Comment: Can you test your server with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ ? Does the result talk about incomplete chain ?

Comment: @Tom, ssllabs.com doesn't allow to check servers on custom port (that is not 443). My server is on 8085. I used http://ssl-checker.online-domain-tools.com instead.  And yes, it returned that my server SSL certificate is untrusted. So, could it be the reason? However, desktop browsers don't report any issues, the URL string is green.

Comment: Could be a problem with the certificate chain with the intermediate(s) certificate(s).

Answer (score 0):

give the permission in menifest.xml file
with

> `<uses - permissions>`

tag

Comment: Which permission should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed! The problem was with SSL certificates. The server was also unaccessible in Firefox. Everything started to work fine when I've changed the certificates.